# fgets not seeing new line

Tags: php

my simple php code

```
<?

error_reporting(E_ALL);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('show_errors', 1);
$file = "ftpfile.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if(!filesize($file)>0) {
        echo "File is empty!";
    }
    else {
    while (($ftpservers = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

        echo $ftpservers. "\n\r";

    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);






        }
?>
```

my textfile

```
ftp.server:username:password    
ftp.server:username:password    
ftp.server:username:password    
ect..
```

running this code returns this

```
ftp.server:username:passwordftp.server:username:passwordftp.server:username:password
ect..
```

why is `fgets` returning the textfile in spades of three?

Comment: are you sure you didn't meant "\r\n" instead of "\n\r"?

Answer (score 1):

There is a note about problems with line endings on the [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/function.fgets.php) documentation page:

> If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when 
>   reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   `auto_detect_line_endings` run-time configuration option
>   may help resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just an guess but are you sure the source file contains no spaces between ftp.server:username:password and the next entry?